# In MS Access 2016, can you create a checkbox or yes/no field that synchronizes with other checkboxes that meet a certain criteria?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Picture of my relevant fields simplified for this example:

[image]

I am currently working on updating a database in Access for work that has more or less been just a spreadsheet up to this point. As such, I have a lot of information stored on a single table and I'm looking to avoid creating new tables that have to be manually filled in if possible.   I track our purchases, confirming whether or not all the items on a particular purchase order or "PO" has come in, or if that PO only came in with a partial shipment.  This database does not track POs as they are created, only as they are received by shipping, so I do not have a separate table that lists all the POs.

I am trying to create checkboxes in my table that synchronize with other checkboxes of the same PO, so when I receive the final shipment in for a PO, I can click "Order Complete?" (see linked image above) and all of the checkboxes with that same PO# will also be selected.

So far, in my fairly limited Access knowledge, I have attempted to make a new table from a query that listed only shipments with PO#s and then removed duplicate PO#s. I put the same "Order Complete?" field in the new table and then linked the PO# field on both tables and the Order Complete? field on both tables, but this didn't match them up.  My coding knowledge is fairly limited and a little rusty so I was wondering if there was any simple way to do this without a really deep dive into coding.

Comment: You should normalize data structure and have a master table of PONums and dependent table of PODetails. Otherwise, yes, code can manage populating yes/no field. Use UPDATE action SQL. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: So outside of restructuring to the database to incorporate multiple tables, I would just have to use an update query each time?

Comment: Access has to do the query you don't.  Access can import anything in Excel with the click of a button once you set it up.  Go to the data tab, choose external data and start playing with the wizard.  Figure out a normalized data structure then import all the excel data into those tables(model).  Next don't touch those tables directly!  Use forms to (View) the data.  then when the User clicks a shipment have access run some queries and vba code behind the scenes to check if the entire shipment is done  and if so have access mark the entire shipment finished near instantaneously.